# Как исправить функции?

Tags: python, функции

Я сделала следующий код

```
def del_ds():   
    doc = input("Введите номер полки: ")
    a = list(directories.values())
    if doc in a:
            print ("На полке есть документы, удалите их перед удалением полки. Текущий перечень полок: ", list(directories.keys()))
    else: 
        del(directories[doc])
        print ("Полка удалена. Текущий перечень полок:", list(directories.keys()))
    return
```

Сами полки в словаре:

```
directories = {
    '1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
    '2': ['10006'],
    '3': []
}
```

Ключи - это полки 1,2,3. Документы - это значения этих полок. Необходимо, чтобы при наличии в ключе значения полка не удалялась. Сейчас она удаляется в любом случае, независимо от наличия значений в ней. Как мне записать проверку наличия значения в ключе и если, есть пара ключ-значение, полка не удалялась бы?

Comment: приведите пример вашего `directories`. Покажите что собираетесь ввести в `input("Введите номер полки: ")` и какой результат вы ожидаете получить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно надо взять список документов с полки `directories[doc]`

И поместить его в условие, которое проверит пустой ли список:

```
if directories[doc]:
    # Если список не пустой, мы попадем сюда и не позволим удалить полку
else:
    # Окажемся здесь, если в списке ничего нет, и сможем успешно удалить полку
```

---

Перед всем еще стоит проверить:

```
if doc not in directories:
    # Если ввели несуществующий номер полки, окажемся здесь и сообщим об этом
else:
    # Тут мы уже уверены, что directories[doc] существует и мы не получим ошибку
    # Можно продолжать работу
```

Comment: я поняла о чем вы) Я заменила строчки в коде из вопроса  `a = list(directories.values())
    if doc in a:`   на  `if directories[doc]: ` Все работает) Спасибо!